# Where to put global exception handler in Gtk# application?

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, gtk#

I've started new Gtk# solution with MonoDevelop. Now where I can put **global** exception handler that popups a dialog to user with stack traces etc? Is there any existing libraries that can do this?

Something like https://exceptionreporter.codeplex.com/

Main.cs:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace foobar
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   
    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException` event](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=E%3aGLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException).

Its [argument of type `GLib.UnhandledExceptionArgs Class`](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aGLib.UnhandledExceptionArgs) contains an [`ExitApplication` property](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=P%3aGLib.UnhandledExceptionArgs.ExitApplication) that can be used to control whether the application should exit due to the exception.